# showing an improper integral converges using p series

Tags: calculus

I want to check whether $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^6} dx$ converges.

I know $1 + x^6 > x^6  $ and so $\frac{1}{1 + x^6} < \frac{1}{x^6}$ and we know $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^6}dx$ converges since it is p-series with $p>1$. So, out original integral must converge. Is this correct?

Comment: The integrals $\int_0^\infty\frac1{x^\alpha}\mathrm dx$ are **all** divergent. But if you split the integral you can use the fact that $\int_0^1\frac1{x^\alpha}\mathrm dx$ converges for $\alpha <1$ and that $\int_1^\infty\frac1{x^\alpha}\mathrm dx$ converges for $\alpha >1$.

Comment: As an aside, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\dfrac{x^{k-1}}{1+x^n}~dx ~=~ \dfrac\pi n~\csc\bigg(k~\dfrac\pi n\bigg).$

Comment: Split the integral into one from 0 to 1 and one from 1 to ∞. The second one exists and so does the first for in the latter the integrand is bounded by 1.

Answer (score 0):

The integral of $1/x^6$ converges near infinity but diverges near 0. You need to bound the original function with something that does not diverge near 0, like $\frac1{1+x^2}.$ Or patch your upper bound with some constant near 0.